# Is a typhoon/hurricane also affected by Magnus Effect?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex, weather

We all know that typhoons move as they rotate.

Comment: Are you referring to the Coriolis effect? Please make yourself more clear.

Answer (score 0):

According to the NOAA (US National Ocean Service), The only difference between a hurricane and a typhoon is the location where the storm occurs. In the North Atlantic, central North Pacific, and eastern North Pacific, the term hurricane is used. The same type of disturbance in the Northwest Pacific is called a typhoon.

So, since the Magnus effect affects hurricanes, it should affect typhoons also. Hurricanes in the Northern Hemisphere move in a counterclockwise direction. Since typhoons also lie in the Northern Hemisphere, they will also move in the same direction unless affected by other dominating factors.